# An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::astor-0.7.1-py_0'

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, virtualenv

I'm trying to install an Anaconda virtual environment on my Mac with the CPU version of Tensorflow 13.1.

I am running OS X 10.11.

The Anaconda virtual environment installation failed because:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::astor-0.7.1-py_0'.
```

The same command worked properly on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

```
$ conda create -n tf python=3.6 tensorflow
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.13
  latest version: 4.6.14

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

  added / updated specs: 
    - python=3.6
    - tensorflow


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    markdown-3.1               |           py36_0         113 KB
    absl-py-0.7.1              |           py36_0         154 KB  conda-forge
    protobuf-3.7.1             |   py36h6de7cb9_0         633 KB  conda-forge
    h5py-2.9.0                 |nompi_py36h35dc34b_1102         965 KB  conda-forge
    grpcio-1.16.1              |   py36h044775b_1         944 KB
    tensorflow-1.13.1          |           py36_0        57.2 MB  conda-forge
    tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0|   py36h24bf2e0_0         472 KB  conda-forge
    tensorboard-1.13.1         |           py36_0         3.3 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        63.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    absl-py:              0.7.1-py36_0                  conda-forge
    astor:                0.7.1-py_0                    conda-forge
    c-ares:               1.15.0-h1de35cc_1001          conda-forge
    ca-certificates:      2019.3.9-hecc5488_0           conda-forge
    certifi:              2019.3.9-py36_0               conda-forge
    gast:                 0.2.2-py_0                    conda-forge
    grpcio:               1.16.1-py36h044775b_1                    
    h5py:                 2.9.0-nompi_py36h35dc34b_1102 conda-forge
    hdf5:                 1.10.4-nompi_h0cbb7df_1106    conda-forge
    keras-applications:   1.0.7-py_1                    conda-forge
    keras-preprocessing:  1.0.9-py_1                    conda-forge
    libblas:              3.8.0-8_openblas              conda-forge
    libcblas:             3.8.0-8_openblas              conda-forge
    libcxx:               8.0.0-2                       conda-forge
    libcxxabi:            8.0.0-2                       conda-forge
    libedit:              3.1.20181209-hb402a30_0                  
    libffi:               3.2.1-h6de7cb9_1006           conda-forge
    libgfortran:          3.0.1-0                       conda-forge
    liblapack:            3.8.0-8_openblas              conda-forge
    libprotobuf:          3.7.1-hfbae3c0_0              conda-forge
    markdown:             3.1-py36_0                               
    ncurses:              6.1-h0a44026_1002             conda-forge
    numpy:                1.16.3-py36hdf140aa_0         conda-forge
    openblas:             0.3.6-hd44dcd8_1              conda-forge
    openssl:              1.1.1b-h01d97ff_2             conda-forge
    pip:                  19.1-py36_0                   conda-forge
    protobuf:             3.7.1-py36h6de7cb9_0          conda-forge
    python:               3.6.8-haf84260_0                         
    readline:             7.0-hcfe32e1_1001             conda-forge
    scipy:                1.2.1-py36hbd7caa9_1          conda-forge
    setuptools:           41.0.1-py36_0                 conda-forge
    six:                  1.12.0-py36_1000              conda-forge
    sqlite:               3.28.0-ha441bb4_0                        
    tensorboard:          1.13.1-py36_0                 conda-forge
    tensorflow:           1.13.1-py36_0                 conda-forge
    tensorflow-estimator: 1.13.0-py36h24bf2e0_0         conda-forge
    termcolor:            1.1.0-py_2                    conda-forge
    tk:                   8.6.9-ha441bb4_1001           conda-forge
    werkzeug:             0.15.2-py_0                   conda-forge
    wheel:                0.33.2-py36_0                 conda-forge
    xz:                   5.2.4-h1de35cc_1001           conda-forge
    zlib:                 1.2.11-h1de35cc_1004          conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
markdown-3.1         | 113 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
absl-py-0.7.1        | 154 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
protobuf-3.7.1       | 633 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
h5py-2.9.0           | 965 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
grpcio-1.16.1        | 944 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
tensorflow-1.13.1    | 57.2 MB   | ##################################### | 100% 
tensorflow-estimator | 472 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
tensorboard-1.13.1   | 3.3 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::astor-0.7.1-py_0'.
OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

With --debug:

```
$ conda --debug create -n tf python=3.6 tensor flow
...

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

  added / updated specs: 
    - python=3.6
    - tensorflow


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    liblapack-3.8.0            |      10_openblas           6 KB  conda-forge
    libblas-3.8.0              |      10_openblas           6 KB  conda-forge
    libcblas-3.8.0             |      10_openblas           6 KB  conda-forge
    werkzeug-0.15.4            |             py_0         254 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         273 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    absl-py:              0.7.1-py36_0                  conda-forge
    astor:                0.7.1-py_0                    conda-forge
    c-ares:               1.15.0-h1de35cc_1001          conda-forge
    ca-certificates:      2019.3.9-hecc5488_0           conda-forge
    certifi:              2019.3.9-py36_0               conda-forge
    gast:                 0.2.2-py_0                    conda-forge
    grpcio:               1.16.1-py36h044775b_1                    
    h5py:                 2.9.0-nompi_py36h35dc34b_1102 conda-forge
    hdf5:                 1.10.4-nompi_h0cbb7df_1106    conda-forge
    keras-applications:   1.0.7-py_1                    conda-forge
    keras-preprocessing:  1.0.9-py_1                    conda-forge
    libblas:              3.8.0-10_openblas             conda-forge
    libcblas:             3.8.0-10_openblas             conda-forge
    libcxx:               8.0.0-2                       conda-forge
    libcxxabi:            8.0.0-2                       conda-forge
    libedit:              3.1.20181209-hb402a30_0                  
    libffi:               3.2.1-h6de7cb9_1006           conda-forge
    libgfortran:          3.0.1-0                       conda-forge
    liblapack:            3.8.0-10_openblas             conda-forge
    libprotobuf:          3.7.1-hfbae3c0_0              conda-forge
    markdown:             3.1-py36_0                               
    ncurses:              6.1-h0a44026_1002             conda-forge
    numpy:                1.16.3-py36hdf140aa_0         conda-forge
    openblas:             0.3.6-hd44dcd8_2              conda-forge
    openssl:              1.1.1b-h01d97ff_2             conda-forge
    pip:                  19.1.1-py36_0                            
    protobuf:             3.7.1-py36h6de7cb9_0          conda-forge
    python:               3.6.8-haf84260_0                         
    readline:             7.0-hcfe32e1_1001             conda-forge
    scipy:                1.2.1-py36hbd7caa9_1          conda-forge
    setuptools:           41.0.1-py36_0                 conda-forge
    six:                  1.12.0-py36_1000              conda-forge
    sqlite:               3.28.0-ha441bb4_0                        
    tensorboard:          1.13.1-py36_0                 conda-forge
    tensorflow:           1.13.1-py36_0                 conda-forge
    tensorflow-estimator: 1.13.0-py36h24bf2e0_0         conda-forge
    termcolor:            1.1.0-py_2                    conda-forge
    tk:                   8.6.9-ha441bb4_1001           conda-forge
    werkzeug:             0.15.4-py_0                   conda-forge
    wheel:                0.33.4-py36_0                 conda-forge
    xz:                   5.2.4-h1de35cc_1001           conda-forge
    zlib:                 1.2.11-h1de35cc_1004          conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:execute(594): prepared package cache actions:
  cache_actions:
    CacheUrlAction<url=u'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2'>
    CacheUrlAction<url=u'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2'>
    CacheUrlAction<url=u'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2'>
    CacheUrlAction<url=u'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0.tar.bz2'>
  extract_actions:
    ExtractPackageAction<source_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas'>
    ExtractPackageAction<source_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas'>
    ExtractPackageAction<source_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas'>
    ExtractPackageAction<source_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0.tar.bz2', target_full_path=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0'>

DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGABRT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGINT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGTERM
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGQUIT
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(824): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(396): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/osx-64/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 6617
DEBUG conda.gateways.connection.download:download(45): 
>>GET /conda-forge/osx-64/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2 HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.5.13 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/15.6.0 OSX/10.11.6
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: keep-alive

<<HTTPS 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=1200
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-Ray: 4d88683e4b06cab0-YYZ
< Content-Type: application/x-tar
< Date: Fri, 17 May 2019 20:40:34 GMT
< ETag: "02a94cc509b50967f377357243e8d3cd"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Fri, 17 May 2019 21:00:34 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 17 May 2019 06:07:30 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dc2b121bf06b5109346d76beb122a376b1558125634; expires=Sat, 16-May-20 20:40:34 GMT; path=/; domain=.anaconda.org; HttpOnly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: Mr4JMNq8GnazEr4guyZVeElDqyAxbEyw7BUPZe5EoU04HOaIzynL+6/Z397Kn0J+rcyZ1q3GjZ8=
< x-amz-request-id: 830E1A3C2328D448
< x-amz-version-id: null
< Content-Length: 6617
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.443875

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.create:extract_tarball(163): extracting /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2
  to /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/liblapack-3.8.0-10_openblas
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(396): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/osx-64/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 6643
DEBUG conda.gateways.connection.download:download(45): 
>>GET /conda-forge/osx-64/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2 HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.5.13 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/15.6.0 OSX/10.11.6
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: __cfduid=dc2b121bf06b5109346d76beb122a376b1558125634

<<HTTPS 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=1200
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-Ray: 4d88683f7dbccab0-YYZ
< Content-Type: application/x-tar
< Date: Fri, 17 May 2019 20:40:34 GMT
< ETag: "6a61ff3616c1e2b1ff32f10d21adf568"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Fri, 17 May 2019 21:00:34 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 17 May 2019 06:07:30 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: NiQigupEKslVxABuKpECMFbMW1b2feS+cYfZhoTg7vsrMBhRPIgirefNvBNoZIGD9/D718gB3qs=
< x-amz-request-id: 1D18102A56454D04
< x-amz-version-id: null
< Content-Length: 6643
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.119374

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.create:extract_tarball(163): extracting /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2
  to /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libblas-3.8.0-10_openblas
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(396): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/osx-64/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 6619
DEBUG conda.gateways.connection.download:download(45): 
>>GET /conda-forge/osx-64/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2 HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.5.13 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/15.6.0 OSX/10.11.6
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: __cfduid=dc2b121bf06b5109346d76beb122a376b1558125634

<<HTTPS 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=1200
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-Ray: 4d886840e8a9cab0-YYZ
< Content-Type: application/x-tar
< Date: Fri, 17 May 2019 20:40:34 GMT
< ETag: "1b0b4e3b1871e138e40e9e2419a41477"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Fri, 17 May 2019 21:00:34 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 17 May 2019 06:07:30 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: Qw/cugiYocIB40OF6InXeWSRNBv4snLQXj+z/WlL2AXdJPhtmx/SHZwAH2t5ndm7QXCE6cbJNUE=
< x-amz-request-id: FC907C1A856E4C39
< x-amz-version-id: null
< Content-Length: 6619
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.135021

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.create:extract_tarball(163): extracting /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas.tar.bz2
  to /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libcblas-3.8.0-10_openblas
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(396): https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/noarch/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 259675
DEBUG conda.gateways.connection.download:download(45): 
>>GET /conda-forge/noarch/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0.tar.bz2 HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.5.13 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/15.6.0 OSX/10.11.6
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: __cfduid=dc2b121bf06b5109346d76beb122a376b1558125634

<<HTTPS 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=1200
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-Ray: 4d8868428bafcab0-YYZ
< Content-Type: application/x-tar
< Date: Fri, 17 May 2019 20:40:34 GMT
< ETag: "1c2c4c2c29736f513326eb0ff9e5e3dd"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Fri, 17 May 2019 21:00:34 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 15 May 2019 22:07:10 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: D9AHuzFj2xwcSsGQiOiBLpus6gq+JPyh3/2MGhIVgBc0COODBnWJXn8NurjJJIFnt74txqZoTJk=
< x-amz-request-id: D7E0A13303FF249B
< x-amz-version-id: null
< Content-Length: 259675
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.121285

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.create:extract_tarball(163): extracting /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0.tar.bz2
  to /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/werkzeug-0.15.4-py_0
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 6
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 2
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 15
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 3
Preparing transaction: ...working... DEBUG conda.core.link:_get_python_version(624): found in current transaction python version 3.6.8
done
Verifying transaction: ...working... INFO conda.core.link:verify(217): (ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: conda-forge::tensorboard-1.13.1-py36_0, conda-forge::tensorflow-1.13.1-py36_0
  path: 'bin/tensorboard'

,)
done
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGABRT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGINT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGTERM
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGQUIT
Executing transaction: ...working... INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::c-ares-1.15.0-h1de35cc_1001 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/c-ares-1.15.0-h1de35cc_1001

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.3.9-hecc5488_0 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/ca-certificates-2019.3.9-hecc5488_0

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::libgfortran-3.0.1-0 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/libgfortran-3.0.1-0

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::xz-5.2.4-h1de35cc_1001 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/xz-5.2.4-h1de35cc_1001

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::zlib-1.2.11-h1de35cc_1004 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/zlib-1.2.11-h1de35cc_1004

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::openblas-0.3.6-hd44dcd8_2 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/openblas-0.3.6-hd44dcd8_2

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1b-h01d97ff_2 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/openssl-1.1.1b-h01d97ff_2

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::tk-8.6.9-ha441bb4_1001 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/tk-8.6.9-ha441bb4_1001

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(553): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::astor-0.7.1-py_0 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf
  source=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/pkgs/astor-0.7.1-py_0

DEBUG conda.gateways.subprocess:subprocess_call(46): executing>> "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf/bin/python3.6" -Wi -m compileall -q -l -i /var/folders/nj/nphdkhyj6s1dttb0pd9zb2wc0000gn/T/tmpqwQVY3 -j 0
DEBUG conda.core.link:_execute_actions(567): Error in action #18 for pkg_idx #8 CompileMultiPycAction(source_short_paths=(u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__init__.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/code_gen.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/codegen.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/file_util.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/node_util.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/op_util.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/rtrip.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/source_repr.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/string_repr.py', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/tree_walk.py'), _execute_successful=False, target_short_paths=(u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/code_gen.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/codegen.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/file_util.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/node_util.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/op_util.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/rtrip.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/source_repr.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/string_repr.cpython-36.pyc', u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/tree_walk.cpython-36.pyc'), prefix_path_data=None, _verified=True, target_prefix=u'/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf', prefix_paths_data=[PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/code_gen.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/codegen.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/file_util.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/node_util.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/op_util.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/rtrip.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/source_repr.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/string_repr.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file'), PathDataV1(_path=u'lib/python3.6/site-packages/astor/__pycache__/tree_walk.cpython-36.pyc', path_type=u'pyc_file')])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 561, in _execute_actions
    action.execute()
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 576, in execute
    self.target_prefix, self.transaction_context['target_python_version'])
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/create.py", line 364, in compile_multiple_pyc
    result = subprocess_call(command, raise_on_error=False, path=prefix)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/subprocess.py", line 47, in subprocess_call
    p = Popen(command_arg, cwd=path, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env=env)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::astor-0.7.1-py_0 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #8 from axn_idx #18
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::astor-0.7.1-py_0'.
OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: ...working... INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::tk-8.6.9-ha441bb4_1001 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #7 from axn_idx #-1
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1b-h01d97ff_2 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #6 from axn_idx #-1
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::openblas-0.3.6-hd44dcd8_2 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #5 from axn_idx #-1
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::zlib-1.2.11-h1de35cc_1004 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #4 from axn_idx #-1
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::xz-5.2.4-h1de35cc_1001 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #3 from axn_idx #-1
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::libgfortran-3.0.1-0 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #2 from axn_idx #-1
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.3.9-hecc5488_0 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #1 from axn_idx #-1
INFO conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(595): ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::c-ares-1.15.0-h1de35cc_1001 <===
  prefix=/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/envs/tf

DEBUG conda.core.link:_reverse_actions(597): reversing pkg_idx #0 from axn_idx #-1
done
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 6
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 2
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 15
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 253, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 282, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 228, in execute
    self._execute(tuple(concat(interleave(itervalues(self.prefix_action_groups)))))
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 526, in _execute
    rollback_excs,
CondaMultiError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

when I install tf1.13.1 meet with this problem, I tryed install astor alone. It works:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 astor
```

or:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 astor
```